# Getting exception when trying to save access token in redis

Tags: java, spring-security, redis, oauth-2.0

I am trying to save my oauth2 access token in redis. At run time I am getting an exception in RedisTokenStore class while trying to save the access token.
The Exception is - 
`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnection.set([B[B)V`

Redis Server - 4.0.1

In my Authorization Server I have added this

```
@Autowired
private RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

@Bean
public TokenStore tokenStore() {
    return new RedisTokenStore(connectionFactory);
}
```

Comment: That error means version mismatches in your dependencies.

Comment: Try find on your classpath this class and check what method have. Then as above figure out what version should be on maven/gradle.

Comment: thanks a lot now it's working.